# How to get integer value of a string type data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a url goes like this:

```
https://sitename.com/nhd/my_student/nhd?olympiad=4
```

And by using `\Request::getQueryString()`, I get this string value:

`olympiad=4`

Now I need to get only the number **4** from this string.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  request query method

```
request()->query('olympiad');
```

or

```
$request->query('olympiad');
```

Also `query($key = null, $default = null)` method accept default value as second param.

To get all query params use `$request->query()` so you get all query params in array.

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input-from-the-query-string